# Is there a way calling FindDefaultCredentials successfully using 2nd gen local app engine (dev_appserver.py)?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, credentials

I'm developing an app engine application using the "go111" runtime. According to [Migrating your App Engine app from Go 1.9 to Go 1.11](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/go-differences) accessing the datastore should be done using [package datastore](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore). However, calling [google.FindDefaultCredentials](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2/google#FindDefaultCredentials) fails with "could not find default credentials".
Any ideas how to access the datastore using default credentials?

Comment: Have you tried using `google.DefaultCredentials`? I thought the `FindDefaultCredentials` method was more for the flex env, but it looks like you might be using the standard env.

Comment: `google.DefaultCredentials` is just an old name of `google.Credentials` which is just the type for holding the credentials. Yes, I'm using the standard environment but using "go111" runtime. I don't know how to access local datastore. Before using the go111 runtime, I simply used the app engine datastore API.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable before starting your application.

With the second generation runtime, if you aren't using any `google.golang.org/appengine` APIs, you do not need to use `dev_appserver.py` -- you can build and start your application normally (`go build` and/or `go run`).

Also, it's very uncommon to explicitly pass the credentials. `cloud.google.com/go` APIs should all automatically find your credentials for you. When you're running locally, setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` environment variables should be enough to get running. See https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_credentials_on_app_engine_standard_environment (note the comment about this being uncommon).

Comment: I understand that setting the env vars would allow me accessing the cloud datastore. But my goal is access the local datastore. That's why I'm using dev_appserver.py (which also starts a datastore instance). Before using the go111 runtime, the datastore API automatically figured out how to access the local datastore. Same go for unit tests: I want the test to access a local (temporary) datastore instance and not the cloud/online datastore.

Answer (score 0):

I just got it working using local app engine SDK by ..

- Passing command line parameter `--support_datastore_emulator=true` to `dev_appserver.py`
- Passing command line parameter `--datastore_emulator_port=9090` to `dev_appserver.py`
- Setting environment variable `DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST` to `localhost:9090` in `app.yaml`
- Setting environment variable `DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID` to `my project id` in `app.yaml`

In my Go 1.11 code, I simply create a new `cloud.google.com/go/datastore` client using `datastore.NewClient(ctx, "")`, which picks up the environment variables and connects to the local datastore emulator (running as part of `dev_appserver.py`).